# unit testing framework for Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: unit-testing, visual-c++-6

Is there a unit testing framework for Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you move to a compiler/IDE released in the past decade.

Comment: @TerryMahaffey:  This probably has to do with legacy code.  I stumbled upon this question because I've been asked to support a large codebase written in MFC and msvc6.0.  The idea is to do as you say and use modern compilers but some unit tests to cover functionality will give me some sense of security going forward.  It's one of the first recommendations of "Working Effectively with Legacy Code"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a C++ programmer, but I think [CppUnit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/) does the trick. I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 1):

You can read [this article](http://gamesfromwithin.com/exploring-the-c-unit-testing-framework-jungle) for list of all C++ unit testing frameworks, and check which one is working with VS6.0

Answer (score 1):

There's a [VC6 port](https://github.com/martinmoene/Catch) of Phil Nash' [Catch test framework](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch).

Catch is easy to start with as it is packaged up as a single header and has no external dependencies other than the C++ standard library.

Test cases are written as self-registering functions or methods, optionally divided into sections. Catch needs only one core assertion macro for comparisons, using standard C operators for the comparison - yet decomposing the full expression and logging both lhs and rhs values.

Comment: There's also a C++98/03 variant of my [lest](https://github.com/martinmoene/lest) header-only test framework that can be used with VC6: [lest_cpp03.hpp](https://github.com/martinmoene/lest/blob/master/lest_cpp03.hpp). lest is inspired on Catch and also has [function-level fixtures](https://github.com/martinmoene/lest#fixture-macros) and [expression-decomposing assertion macros](https://github.com/martinmoene/lest#assertion-macros).

Answer (score 0):

CppUnit requires more work than necessary, particularly the work it takes to create a new test case. The original author, Michael Feathers, published a simplified framework which has been used as the basis for others. I've used [UnitTest++](https://github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp), and am very interested in [googletest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/). Either one will let you create a new test case without having to declare it and manually add it to a suite; the frameworks do that for you.

Comment: Google Test doesn't support VC++6 officially.. In 2009, there were 2182 lines of code changes needed to make it usable with less functionalities and/or with syntax changes..

Comment: UnitTest++ is now at GitHub, see [unittest-cpp](https://github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp).